# Making CAPTCHA accessible to people with disabilities. What approaches have you used?

Tags: forms, webforms, accessibility, captcha

I'm nearing the completion of migrating our existing website to a CMS and I've just finished creating all the various contact forms. The CMS I'm using has CAPTCHA built into it's form builder, which is great, but the only method available is the "decipher-the-noisy-image" method.

This approach works well, but it limits access for people who might have reading or sight disabilities. I've worked around this by having a "help" page which allows those with disabilities to contact us by telephone and I'm considering having a single-field form which says "Send us your email address and we'll contact you". Accessibility is of particular importance to me as a web developer, but from an organisational perspective; so is reducing the amount of form spam we receive.

So what I'd like to know is, has anyone in the community had any experience with other CAPTCHA methods and how have you managed to make them accessible to people with disabilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a blind person I find that [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/learnmore.html) is one of the better CAPTCHA services out there as far as an audio option. The issue with using sms as the only alternative is the fact that many visually impaired users don't have cell phones that allow them to read text messages.

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't expecting to hear from someone who has the very same impairment I'm trying to cater for. I will definately suggest to my supplier that they implement a recaptcha plugin :)

Comment: Ok, then how does a blind person actually respond to this post?

Comment: Hi Jared, I've revisited this question after a couple of years and I'm interested to know, do you still find recaptcha as accessible as it used to be? Especially given that they've recently increased the complexity of the challenges (even, I have a hard time solving them and I don't have any sort of impairment).

Answer (score 2):

A good captcha, like [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/learnmore.html), usually includes an audio CAPTCHA.  Also I have seen a site that will
send a SMS message and you enter the code in the sms (Google-gmail will do this).

I am very interested in this because I am implementing a CAPTCHA in jQuery right now.

Comment: Wow, the SMS one sounds like a great idea - I never thought of that. I can see some scope for abuse using this method though, namely a malicious user could just keep hammering the form to spend your money - unless you had some kind of protection in place for that. Also, as this technique becomes more popular, it wouldn't be out of the question for spammers to code their bots to work with SMS. That's the annoying thing about CAPTCHA, it's a constant arms race. Remember back when "Leave this field blank" used to work? :). Thanks for your comment and insight :)

Comment: SMS is an interesting approach - online banking is starting to jump onboard with it. One downside is it assumes the user has a cellphone and is willing to trust your site with his/her number.

Comment: Also there is usually a cost associated with sending a SMS message.

Comment: I just sent this to a friend of mine in Australia.  When he logs into his bank account the bank uses a SMS message to send him a one-time-cypher(key) via SMS.  They do that for every login.

Answer (score 0):

Many sites, including this one I believe, have an option to play noisy audio with embedded spoken numbers, as an audio equivalent to the traditional CAPTCHA image.

I find the result pretty spooky, actually.  Reminds me of [numbers stations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_station).

Comment: Yes, I heard that one for the first time on a Microsoft website. Spooked the hell out of me, reminded me of the ghostly "Electronic Voice Phenomenon".

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said, audio with each character of the CAPTCHA text spoken for better or worse is a common option provided. If your CMS is PHP-based or if PHP is available on the hosting infrastructure you are using anyway, here's an open source CAPTCHA application with an audio download option:

> http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

I've implemented a production site with phpcaptcha, and it works as advertised.